# libavfilter - reconfigure filter graph using avfilter_graph_parse_ptr returns -22

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I am using `transcode.c` sample from ffmpeg examples and it is working as expected. It uses `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr` to setup filter graph and it works fine.

However, I need change filter graph dynamically and there `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr` fails. It returns -22. I am not certain if it is a valid operation to do (reconfigure)? If it is possible,  does it require more than `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr` and `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr`? libavfilter documentation doesn't say anything about reconfigure or reset existing graph.

I can create a new graph but I am avoiding it since it is affecting the existing buffers.

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: same here, I need this answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you cannot dynamically reconfigure the filter graph. I guess the design is just "static" in that once you've constructed it, you're not supposed to change it.

You've two options. One is to completely destroy the graph and recreate it.

Another option is (if you're using C++) encapsulate a filter inside It's own class with one graph for each one. Then you'll have a queue or list where you can add the filters to and just pass the frames through them every time. There's not much performance penalty, probably just more memory you'll use and more code to write. This was the approach I took by the way and it works